# Convert string array of objects to json in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a string array of objects coming to a react native frontend. I'm not sure how to convert this to a json to read it in front end. This is the string I need to convert:

[{_id=63c1400ae18737cd3c67d8d4, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T20:26:54.150Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=11820, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}, {_id=63c12467e18737cd3c67d809, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T15:03:53.000Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=10080, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}]

Comment: Hi! This is a string? How do you receive it? Can you share other information?

Comment: Yes this is a string. I'm getting this from a WritableMap from android backend. Issue is it's converted to a string. I have to convert this from ui to read

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this:

```js
let strval =
  "[{_id=63c1400ae18737cd3c67d8d4, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T20:26:54.150Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=11820, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}, {_id=63c12467e18737cd3c67d809, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T15:03:53.000Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=10080, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}]";

strval = strval.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

const splittedObj = strval.split("},");

let arr = [];

splittedObj.forEach((e, i) => {
  e = e.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
  let obj = {};

  e.split(",").map((element) => {
    const splittedElement = element.trim().split("=");
    obj[splittedElement[0]] = splittedElement[1];
  });
  arr.push(obj);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This doesn't work array of  nested  objects

Comment: Try the updated code and let me know this is something you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let stringArr =
  '[{_id=63c1400ae18737cd3c67d8d4, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T20:26:54.150Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=11820, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}, {_id=63c12467e18737cd3c67d809, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T15:03:53.000Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=10080, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}]';
  
console.log("given array -> ",stringArr)

stringArr = stringArr.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').slice(1).slice(0, -1).split(',');

stringArr = stringArr.map(e => {
  const trimString = e.trim();
  const equalSpilt = trimString.split('=');
  const key = equalSpilt[0];
  const obj = {};
  obj[key] = equalSpilt[1];
  return obj;
});

console.log("final output -> ",stringArr)
```

possible if you can convert your array to string

```
let stringArr =
  '[{_id=63c1400ae18737cd3c67d8d4, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T20:26:54.150Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=11820, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}, {_id=63c12467e18737cd3c67d809, user_id=1185.0, device_serial=544008293, site_id=2000000.0, datetime=2023-01-13T15:03:53.000Z, timezone=Asia/Seoul, code=10080, offset=3.24E7, __v=0.0, device_name=544008293, user_name=sanj, user_key=7722352345}]';

stringArr = stringArr.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').slice(1).slice(0, -1).split(',');

stringArr = stringArr.map(e => {
  const trimString = e.trim();
  const equalSpilt = trimString.split('=');
  const key = equalSpilt[0];
  const obj = {};
  obj[key] = equalSpilt[1];
  return obj;
});
```

Comment: This works almost, but when I try to access value it's not as expected.  eg: When I print stringArr[0] ====> it gives {"_id": "63c1400ae18737cd3c67d8d4"} this one. Not the 1st object. Any idea?

Comment: that is the 1st object, isn't it, whats wrong